# Laravel Eloquent Results not giving Options to View Attributes when Using dd

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5, group-by, eloquent

I'm querying from my DB using a JOIN statement. When I use the dd() function to print out my results I get the correct number of results, however, for some reason, the attributes array is not the visible array.

[image]
Here's my code...

```
<?php

$usersResults = User::where('place', '=', $place)
    ->join("destinations", 'users.id', "=", "destinations.user_id")
    ->select("users.*", "destinations.created_at")
    ->groupBy("users.id")->get();

dd($usersResults);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal. When you have a lot of results `dd()` wont' display all of the data. For this element you can use for example `dd($userResults[7])` or `dd($userResults[7]->toArray())` and this will probably include all information in output.

But keep in mind `dd()` is only used for displaying. So you cannot see all the data using dd, but they are in there, so in case you want to do anything with them (for example display in HTML view or export to file) there won't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this issue I often have a key binding setup that wraps my selection inside of the following:

```
die('<pre>'.print_r($SELECTION, true).'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use  {{ print_r($userResults->toArray(), true) }}. It will display all the records that you are looking for. Also see Marcin Nabiałek's answer above.